# How to pass dynamic value to a JSON String

Tags: java, json

I have constructed a JSON String this way , but cannot able to pass dynamic values to it

```
String input = "{\r\n" + 
                    "    \"Level\": 0,\r\n" + 
                    "    \"Name\": \"String\",\r\n" + 
                    "    \"msgName\": \"String\",\r\n" + 
                    "    \"ActualMessage\": \"String\",\r\n" + 
                    "    \"TimeStamp\": \"/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/\"\r\n" + 
                    "}" ;

String message = "this is value  want to pass to the ActualMessage attribute " ;

I need to pass dynamic value to the ActaulMessage atribute
```

Please tell me how ?

i have tried number of trial and errors but couldn't able to succeed.

Comment: Have the object that's creating the JSON message and owns the dynamic data inject it for you.

Comment: By "pass a dynamic value" do you mean templating - that at a point in time you want to put the *value* of `message`at a specific location inside the JSON string; or do you mean binding - that you want to bind the *variable* `message` in some way that so that over time as the variable's value changes, the JSON string value of `input` changes to reflect it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string concatenation.

```
String message = "this is value  want to pass to the ActualMessage attribute " ;
String input = "{\r\n" + 
               "\"Level\": 0,\r\n" + 
               "\"Name\": \"String\",\r\n" + 
               "\"msgName\": \"String\",\r\n" + 
               "\"ActualMessage\": \"" + message + "\",\r\n" + 
               "\"TimeStamp\": \"/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/\"\r\n" + 
               "}" ;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `String.format()` for this? for example, to pass a "dynamic value" declare a place holder in the text:

```
String input = "insert %s in the string"; // here %s is the placeholder
input = String.format(input, "value");    // replace %s with actual value
```

Now `input` will contain the string `"insert value in the string"`. In your example, change this line:

```
"    \"msgName\": \"String\",\r\n"
```

Replace it with this:

```
"    \"msgName\": \"%s\",\r\n"
```

Now you can perform the substitution:

```
input = String.format(input, message);
```

Notice that the first parameter in the `format()` method has a lot more of options, and that you can pass more than one argument to be replaced. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for the `Formatter` class.

Comment: I'm showing how to perform a string substitution in general, OP's input in the question is just a string, so it'll work just the same

Answer (score 1):

if you want to manipulate Json please consider [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). your problem can be addressed as follows.

```
String input = "{\r\n" + 
                    "    \"Level\": 0,\r\n" + 
                    "    \"Name\": \"String\",\r\n" + 
                    "    \"msgName\": \"MessageName\",\r\n" + 
                    "    \"ActualMessage\": \"%s\",\r\n" + 
                    "    \"TimeStamp\": \"/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/\"\r\n" + 
                    "}" ;

String message = "this is value  want to pass to the ActualMessage attribute " ;
String output=String.format(input,message);
//this will replace %s with the content of message variable.
```