# Customize Json Patch as per the requiremnent

Tags: java, json, rest, patch, json-patch

I am using [Json Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) library to perfrom a Patch operation using REST. Now I have the follwoing json document:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "ref":{"r1":1,"r2":2},  // header level
    "child":[
                {
                    "childId":1,
                    "ref":{"cc1":1,"cc2":2}   // line level
                },
                {
                    "childId":2,
                    "ref":{"cc3":2}    // line level
                }
            ]
}
```

Now As per [Json Patch doc](http://jsonpatch.com/) we at the header level we can update the **ref r1** using the following path `/ref/r1` .

Now I am trying to perform operation on the line level **child ref**. Since child is an array I can use the path `/child/0/ref/cc1`. But as can be seen from the **path** I have to specify the index also which is 0 in the previous case.

Now for API consumers asking them to give the index of the array become difficult. So is there any way to customize json patch so that we can bypass the index requirement or what are the other ways to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in JSON-Patch, i've just read about it.
from what i understood, is the most important part is to let the API consumers access to your JSON without giving them index,

I think **hashmap** would help in this case, by getting the index of each element and generate a specific ID for it, then you can save them in the **hashmap list**, *each index has its own ID*.

a sample:

`HashMap<String, String> elementIndex = new HashMap<[UUID], [elementIndex]>();`
*you can choose whatever DataType you want, not necessary String*

In this case it doesn't matter which index number, it is all about the fixed UUID.
So the path will be in this case `/child/{UUID}/ref/cc1` also when you receive the path you can access the **UUID** and replace it with its elementIndex, now you have the correct path which is `/child/0/ref/cc1`

and if you want to know how to pass a dynamic value to a JSON Object, there are multiple ways to do it,
this question will help:

[How to pass dynamic value to a JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213192/how-to-pass-dynamic-value-to-a-json-string), -**Convert the JSONObject to String before**-

**NOTE**: It is not necessary to replace it with index, you can do it the way you like could be.

And i believe there are better answers if someone knows more about JSON-patch.
i hope that was helpful, or at least gives you an idea about how to solve it.